# CyberPanelによるSSL証明書発行後の証明書エラーについて

Tags: linux, ssl, letsencrypt

私は「AlmaLinux 8 64bit with CyberPanel」を利用して、新規で取得したDNSに対するSSL証明書を発行しようとしています。

しかし、DNSの伝搬が完了後、Let's Encryptによる証明書インポートを試みたところ、証明書自体は発行できましたが、SAN値が設定されていないことによる証明書エラーを引き起こしているようです。

#### 問題点

SAN値が設定されていないことによる証明書エラー。

```
Issuer: C = US, ST = Denial, L = Springfield, O = Dis, CN = MyDomain.com
```

Webサイト上でのエラー内容

```
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

[image: 証明書エラー内容]

#### 試したこと

- VPSにインストールされている証明書を一度削除し、再度CyberPanelでLet's EncryptによるSSL証明書をインポートしなおしました。（結果：解決せず）
- DNS伝搬が完全に完了していないのではないかと思い、DNS Checkerで確認しました。（結果：DNSは完全に伝搬されているので問題なし）
- 既存のprivate.pemファイルを利用してSAN値を追加した新しい証明書の作成（以下コマンド）

  ```
  openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privkey.pem -out fullchain.pem -subj "/CN=MyDomain.com" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:MyDomain.com,DNS:www.MyDomain.com,IP:MyIP" -days 365 -sha256
  ```

#### 解決したい内容

既に存在するSSL証明書にSAN値を設定したいです。（SAN値を設定するコマンドを提供いただきたいです。）

補足
この分野について知見が浅いので、必要な情報全て提供できていないかもしれないので、別途必要な情報などございましたらコメントでご指摘ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。